# xpretocmd: Why are my arguments not working?

Tags: etoolbox, arguments, xpatch

I just tried to keep track of my current chapter name, because I use the first letter for certain namings in my document, so I wrote this code to save it:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcommand{\currentchapter}{Not set yet}

\xpretocmd{\chapter}
{%
    \renewcommand{\currentchapter}{#1}%
}{}{}

\begin{document}
\currentchapter
\chapter{Hello}
\currentchapter
\chapter{Goodbye}
\currentchapter

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately this just prints:

```
Not set yet.
#1
#1
```

For the 3 occurrences of my command between the chapters. But my expected output would be:

```
Not set yet.
Hello
Goodbye
```

In other peoples code this usage of arguments seems to work, so I don't understand why it doesn't work here.

Comment: `\chapter` has no arguments, try to out `\show\chapter` to see it. The arguments are grabbed later.

Comment: So, how would I grab these arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\chapter` command doesn't grab arguments, but has first to check for `*` or an optional argument.

In the standard classes the command to patch should be `\@chapter`, but in KoMa classes it is `\scr@@startchapter`. If you want to patch it in order to save the title in `\currentchapter` you can do

```
\makeatletter
\xpretocmd{\scr@@startchapter}{\def\currentchapter{#3}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcommand{\currentchapter}{Not set yet}

\makeatletter
\xpretocmd{\scr@@startchapter}
  {\renewcommand{\currentchapter}{#3}}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\currentchapter
\chapter{Hello}
\currentchapter
\chapter{Goodbye}
\currentchapter

\end{document}
```

Yes, patching commands is a black art.

Comment: @Moraxno If you also want this to work with `\chapter*` commands then you will need a similar modification of `\scr@@startschapter`. Btw, the normal way to thank people on TeX.SX is to up-vote and award green ticks! :)

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for the additional information. Unfortunately, while your solution worked yesterday, today it broke. It seems as if `\xpretocmd{\scr@@startchapter{\renewcommand{\currentchapter}{#3}}{}{}` now interprets #3 not as the argument of the original command but as the String '#3' and I have no idea why this is. I basically changed nothing to my commands, only added some contents to the lists...

Comment: @Moraxno I said that a *similar* modification of `\scr@@startschapter`. If you look in `scrreprt.cls` you will see that you need to use `#2`, rather than `#3`, when you patch `\scr@@startschapter`.

Answer (score 2):

You can patch `\chapterlinesformat`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd\chapterlinesformat{\gdef\currentchapter{#3}}{}{\fail}
\newcommand{\currentchapter}{Not set yet}

\begin{document}
\currentchapter
\chapter{Hello}
\currentchapter
\chapter{Goodbye}
\currentchapter

\end{document}
```

[image]